# Testing a custom rom on pc emulator

Tags: android, sdk, emulation, device, rom

I want to make a custom rom and I would like to test it first in an emulator.
I have made some little things but i can't reach it until the final result
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

you can find answer in [this][1] site.

```
https://wiki.lineageos.org/pages
```

https://wiki.lineageos.org/pages